# A Messy Git Situation

Tags: git, github, version-control

Here's a timeline of what I did with a git repository:

1. forked from a repository called `upstream`, branch `master`
2. made various [unrelated] changes on `master`, pushed to `origin`
3. realized that changes should be made on topic-specific branches, so created those branches (called `to`, `pi`, and `cs`) and `cherry-pick`ed relevant commits from `master`
4. before pushing, `rebase`d `to`, `pi`, and `cs` to `upstream/master`
5. created PRs from `to`, `pi`, and `cs` to `upstream/master`
6. the `to` and `pi` PRs were merged, `cs` wasn't; `pull`ed `upstream/master` to `origin/master` and deleted the `to` and `pi` branches

Now I'm left with a `master` branch that is multiple commits ahead of `upstream/master`, while most of those commits have actually been merged in `upstream` and then pulled to `master`. Every time I make a branch from `origin/master`, I have to `rebase` to undo those commits and base the branch off `upstream/master`.

My questions:

1. How do I fix this so that `origin/master` is even with `upstream/master`? Or is this not really a problem and can be circumvented?
2. What went wrong in the timeline and what should I do next time?

(Information that may be relevant: the repositories are on GitHub, I'm using git v2.7.4 on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, I am prepared to do a `push --force` to `origin/master` if absolutely necessary but I don't have control over `upstream`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make `origin/master` even with `upstream/master` with the following commands:

```
git checkout master
git fetch --all
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push --force
```

which involved a forced `push`, but fixed the issue. The long-term solution is to never commit directly to master, and when `pull`ing from upstream, to always make sure that it will be a fast-forward merge. My topic branches can now be based off `master` and present no problem.

(Note: I was helped in this by the `#git` IRC channel on Freenode.)